# fill html table with mysql data

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I've looked around the net for a while to find a way to fill a HTML table with data from a MYSQL table.

From what i've seen, I have created this, however it only returns the first entry in the table, and not only once, but continues to add it forever.

```
<?php 
  require "connect.php";
  $conn = Connect();
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT handle, email, campaigngroup FROM targets");

 ?>

 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Handle</td>
   <td>Email</td>
   <td>Group</td>
  </tr>

 <?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['handle'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['campaigngroup'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

what would be the best way to go about what I wish to achieve? I would like the HTML table to be as long as the amount of data in the SQL table.

Comment: *"but continues to add it forever"* - what do you mean by that exactly? How many records are there?

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: @Fred-ii- its a while loop, so it continues forever, it will continue until I stop the page from running

Comment: Pagination maybe?

Comment: My comment was a 2-part question: this one: *"How many records are there?"* is the one I need to know also. Millions? 10? 100,000? trillions? Edit: 2???

Comment: records in that SQL table, there are two.

Comment: it's most likely your syntax for the arrays. See the manual on that http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php there are other functions you can use for this and you're using the wrong one. It's trying to move to the next pointer and never finds it, that's why it's looping forever. @IsaacManzi would you like me to make this comment an answer? ;-) from the manual: *"Returns a **numerical** array that corresponds to the fetched row and **moves the internal data pointer** ahead. "*

Comment: I didn't mention the mysqli_ api, I mentioned [this important note/comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042061/fill-html-table-with-mysql-data#comment81031339_47042061), reload it, I edited it. @IsaacManzi Edit: You deleted the comment I was responding to your ping to me.

Comment: if you're going to want to use `$row['string']` you'll have to use `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. You're using a string where a numeric array is used with `mysql_fetch_row()`.

Comment: Infinite scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments:

> it's most likely your syntax for the arrays. See the manual on that http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php there are other functions you can use for this and you're using the wrong one. It's trying to move to the next pointer and never finds it, that's why it's looping forever. @IsaacManzi would you like me to make this comment an answer? ;-) from the manual: "Returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. "

and

> if you're going to want to use `$row['string']` you'll have to use `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. You're using a string where a numeric array is used with `mysql_fetch_row()`.

However, this api is old and should no longer be used in this day and age.

Either use the `mysqli_` or PDO api and if user input is involved, a prepared statement will need to be used. Otherwise, you stand at getting exposed to an SQL injection.

You stated that you tried it with the `mysqli_` api in comments and you were probably using the `mysqli_` equivalent for it, in turn giving you the same result/looping forever.

You can also look into using pagination, which also uses LIMIT to limit records.